# What's wrong with this simple jQuery hover and replace HTML function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

```
var originalContentFirst = $('#first').html();
$('#first').hover(function() {
     $('#first').html('<strong>New HTML</strong>');   
}, function() {
     $('#first').html(originalContentFirst); 
});

var originalContentSecond = $('#second').html();
$('#second').hover(function() {
     $('#second').html('<strong>New HTML</strong>');   
}, function() {
     $('#second').html(originalContentSecond); 
});

var originalContentThird = $('#third').html();
$('#third').hover(function() {
     $('#third').html('<strong>New HTML</strong>');   
}, function() {
     $('#third').html(originalContentThird); 
});

var originalContentFourth = $('#fourth').html();
$('#fourth').hover(function() {
     $('#fourth').html('<strong>New HTML</strong>');   
}, function() {
     $('#fourth').html(originalContentFourth); 
});
```

This was copied and adapted from elsewhere on this website. As you can see, its function is pretty basic. I have 4 divs (terrible ids, I know), and on a hover it should replace the HTML in them with the new HTML. Any idea why this is not doing anything at all? I'm sure I'm missing something rather elementary, but I can't figure out what the hell it is?

Edit: full HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id=first>
     <span>About Me</span>
    </div>
    <div id=second>
      <span>Past Jobs</span>
    </div>
    <div id=third>
      <span>Projects</span>
    </div>
    <div id=fourth>
      <span>About</span>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get any errors in your browsers developer tools console -  `Any idea why this is not working` - define "not working"? Does it ... do nothing? do something unexpected? reprogram your VCR?

Comment: no, I don't get any errors

Comment: share your html as well

Comment: wrap your js in `$(function() { your code here });` - the problem is that when the js executes, the elements do not yet exist

Comment: That fixed it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As Jaromanda X said - you're loading the script ABOVE the html, therefore it has nothing to attach to.

```
$(function() { // this waits until all html loaded

    var originalContentFirst = $('#first').html();
    $('#first').hover(function() {
         $('#first').html('<strong>New HTML</strong>');   
    }, function() {
         $('#first').html(originalContentFirst); 
    });

    var originalContentSecond = $('#second').html();
    $('#second').hover(function() {
         $('#second').html('<strong>New HTML</strong>');   
    }, function() {
         $('#second').html(originalContentSecond); 
    });

    var originalContentThird = $('#third').html();
    $('#third').hover(function() {
         $('#third').html('<strong>New HTML</strong>');   
    }, function() {
         $('#third').html(originalContentThird); 
    });

    var originalContentFourth = $('#fourth').html();
    $('#fourth').hover(function() {
         $('#fourth').html('<strong>New HTML</strong>');   
    }, function() {
         $('#fourth').html(originalContentFourth); 
    });

}); // this closes it
```